# Resize an image to fit the entirety of a JLabel adapting to its size

Tags: java, swing, graphics

before you ask, I've looked up this issue in the website and the solutions provided have, unfortunately, not worked for me, so I must resort to asking it once more to see what could I be doing wrong.

Closest achievement I've had with the code I've got is this (I should most definitely use a try and catch when I retrieve the image, I'll save that for later on):

```
private void asignarTile(Tile tile, JPanel panel){

    if(tile.getTipo() == 0){

        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("pasto.png");
        Image image = ii.getImage();
        Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(32, 32, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ii = new ImageIcon(newimg);
        tile.setIcon(ii);
        panel.add(tile);
    }
}
```

Now, as oblivious as it is, I must mention that the code does work for a specific size, but it won't adapt the size of the image to the JLabel afterwards, that means that first I'll have this:

[image]

But after I resize it I'll have this:

[image]

I think it would be useful to note that Tile extends JLabel, and these are the changes (columna means column, fila means row, maybe I should start writing my code entirely in english)

```
package gui;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Tile extends JLabel{

    private int fila, columna, tipo;

    public int getFila() {
        return fila;
    }

    public void setFila(int x) {
        this.fila = x;
    }

    public int getColumna() {
        return columna;
    }

    public void setColumna(int y) {
        this.columna = y;
    }

    public int getTipo(){
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(int tipo){
        if(tipo >= 0 || tipo <= 6)
            this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public Tile(int x, int y, int tipo) {
        this.setFila(x);
        this.setColumna(y);
        this.setTipo(tipo);
    }

}
```

As a conclusion I must say that I have considered adding a componentListener to the Tile since it extends a JLabel, but I have also tried to resize the image to the label's dimensions to no avail, as it gave me an exception saying that its dimensions were 0, and well, they can't be 0.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Probably an easy answer, but you still haven't accepted answers in your other postings, so I'll pass on this one.

Comment: Oh? That's a new concept, let me fix that, I should be really thankful to you.

I just accepted your answer, I did not see I had to at first, sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try Darryl's [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) for dynamic resizing.

Otherwise you would extend JComponent (instead of JLabel) and do you own custom painting of the image. See [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) for an example of how to paint a scaled image.

Comment: That has certianly helped, it has fixed the gaps on the Y, but not on the X, leaving it like this: http://puu.sh/5dGUh.png

Comment: @krieg, Did you use the proper parameters? It defaults to proportional which you probably don't want.

Comment: which parameters? the ones on StretchIcon's constructor? I can acknowledge that the spacing issues vary according to how I stretch the frame, see: http://puu.sh/5dIjJ.png when I stretch horizontally and this: http://puu.sh/5dIlK.png when I stretch vertically.

Currently I just created a StretchIcon object with the image I want (only parameter for StretchIcon), set it to the tile and add it to the panel.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you try to create or find a larger tile image. If you try to stretch the image, you will degrade it, but this is not so for shrinking.

Comment: I have just fixed it with the parameteres that @camickr told me about, but you have reminded me of an issue that is yet to come. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This code looks good.
Here's a code review suggestion:

- The serializable class *Tile.java* does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long. **Solution:** Add a generated serial version ID to the selected type.